# iOS icon 72x72 and icon 512x512

Tags: ios, icons, in-house-distribution

I'm making an in-house ipad, and I have 72x72 icon for app icon and 512 512 for itunes, so how should I mark in my info.plist that there an icon 72x72 and 512x512 for itunes? Now in icons record I added icon72.png and icon512.png I still didn't understand it from Apple HIG

Comment: If you add the icons in the project summary page it will create the appropriate sections in the info.plist.  iTunes artwork can't be defined there however, and is only done through iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 512x512 image is loaded through iTunesConnect, not your plist. Nonetheless I like to include it in my apps. You are prompted in iTunesConnect when creating a new app so you can't miss it.

Your icons will work if it looks like this (app is currently in the store):
[image: example icon section of plist]

(note some of those are optional)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode 4. You can click on your project, then on your target and under summary tab you'll have GUI to put your icons.

Xcode will automatically update your info.plist.